# Xamarin Forms Tabbed Page to have overlapping Custom View

Tags: xamarin.forms, cross-platform, uiactionsheet

I need to have something like that with XF Tabbed Page:

[image]

I.e., I need some panel which would appear over the whole content (including any tabs) where I can add some custom content. (The reason why I am asking it here, as it wouldn't be an issue in case of common simple page, when I would just have some overlapping view placed on the page).

In functionality it should be something like `Action Sheets`, but be cross-platform (i.e., defined as common XF view) and include custom content.

But it must be **not necessary custom renderers** with actually `Action Sheet` implementation (and `AlertDialog` accordingly to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808608/android-ios-uiactionsheet-equivalent)). It would be perfect to have some view placed somewhere (I don't know where) in the page layout structure to achieve this.

Or `Action Sheet` and `AlertDialog` (with custom renderers) are still the easiest way to have it these days in XF? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ACR User Dialogs](https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs), and you can specify the `UseBottomSheet` option to make the action sheet appear at the bottom. Its available as a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Acr.UserDialogs), so there is no need for any custom renderers.

```
Acr.UserDialogs.ActionSheetConfig  = new Acr.UserDialogs.ActionSheetConfig();
config.UseBottomSheet = true;
config.Title = "My Options";
config.Add(
    "Option 1",
    () => 
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => {
            await DisplayAlert("", "Clicked option 1", "OK");
        });
    },
    null);
config.Cancel = new Acr.UserDialogs.ActionSheetOption("Cancel");
```

And to display it:

```
Acr.UserDialogs.UserDialogs.Instance.ActionSheet(config);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But how I can use some custom view/layout passed to that component?

Comment: Hmm, I don't think it offers support for a custom view, other than custom icons that appear to the left of the text.

Comment: Well, this is just what my question is about: to have `Custom View` in that panel. It's mentioned in the question title. :)